# Trying to JOIN from 2 tables but get another row from a third

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have 3 tables

- users
- topics
- posts

I have successfully been able to JOIN topics and users to display relevant information, but now I am trying to also get "post_content" from `posts` with no luck.

Here is my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, topics.topic_id,
           topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, 
           topics.posted_by, topics.posted, topics.view, topics.reply, posts.post_content 
    FROM topics
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON topics.posted_by = users.user_id
    WHERE topics.category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']) . "' 
    AND topics.sub_category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sub_category']) . "' 
     OR topics.category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']) . "' 
     OR topics.sub_category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sub_category']) . "' ORDER BY topics.posted DESC";
```

I have looked up guilds and how to's on JOINS but getting stumped with this one.

Comment: You have to show your data structure.

Comment: You have to join the `posts` table - `LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.column = topics.column`